# fibers are connected implies that total space is connected in a surjective submersion between manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Could anyone tell me how to prove the following problem?I have no idea! Thank you!

If $f:M\to N$ is a surjective submersion in the category of smooth manifolds, if $N$ is connected, and if $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected for all $y$ in $N$, then $M$ is connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we are given a continuous function $g: M \to \{0,1\}$. It follows from the assumption on $f^{-1}(y)$ being connected, that $g$ is constant on fibers. Since $f: M \to N$ is open and surjective, it is a quotient map. Since $g$ is constant on fibers, it descends to a continuous map $\tilde g: N \to \{0,1\}$ such that $\tilde g \circ f = g$. As $N$ is connected, $\tilde g$ (and hence also $g$) must be constant.

This shows that every continuous map $g: M \to \{0,1\}$ is constant. This is equivalent to the connectedness of $M$.

Comment: Very nice argument: +1